# SQL use a certain field if another is null

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i have an sql2008 server in which i need to calculate a discount.

the fields at play are `SuggestedRetailPrice`, `BasePrice`, and `AdPrice`

The logic is like this:

```
if AdPrice is null
   return baseprice/suggestedretailprice
else
   if AdEndDate < GETDATE() // Ad is still valid
       return adprice/SuggestedRetailPrice
   endif
endif
```

if the above is confusing, here's what I need to do:

Determine whether to use AdPrice or BasePrice depending on if the Ad has expired by comparing AdEndDate to GETDATE(). Then use that field and divide by SuggestedRetailPrice and compare with a value. i.e. `(AdPrice/SuggestedRetailPrice) >= 0.6`

is something like this even possible to do with one query? i know there are case statements but i am not sure if they are applicable to this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also embed a CASE statement within [`ISNULL()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) to simplify it still further:

```
SELECT
    ISNULL
      (
        CASE 
            WHEN AdEndDate < GETDATE() 
            THEN AdPrice 
        END, 
        BasePrice
      ) / SuggestedRetailPrice
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I can't believe I got the AdEndDate / GETDATE comparison backwards :S

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed - `CASE` allows you to project a derived value, even through multiple branches or switch statements. The general format is as follows:

```
SELECT ...
    CASE WHEN AdPrice is null THEN baseprice/suggestedretailprice
       WHEN AdEndDate < GETDATE() -- Ad is still valid
       THEN adprice/SuggestedRetailPrice
       ELSE 42 -- Project a value for the column if the other branches aren't matched
    END AS MyValue
```

Comment: more context: I am doing this within commerce server and so the only part of the query i can access is the where clause. i understand you can't have a "where case.." statement, but it must be "where [some field] = case", so will this not work?

Comment: Either will work - `CASE x WHEN a THEN ... WHEN b THEN ...` is like a same typed `switch` and `CASE WHEN x THEN ... WHEN y` is for an unrelated `if then else` type projection.

Comment: is there any reason why this doesn't work? `(isnull(case when [adend] < getdate() then [adprice] end, [baseprice]))/[SuggestedRetailPrice] > 0.8`

the majority of items it returns match the `> 0.8` condition however there are 3-4 that have a valid ad and the adprice/srp is less than 0.8.

Comment: @sk099 AHiggens query works ok - [SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/61073/1). You might have inverted your date logic - `Ad still valid` would imply `AdEndDate > GETDATE()`